# How to shift row in the table?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this ASP code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row1">
                    <table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
                        <tr>  
                            <td>text:
                            </td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Text") %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                    Height="32" />
                            </td>
                            <td>X:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Lon") %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Y:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Lat") %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

My question is how can I shift **text** row that it will look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Forget what I said before, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row1">
                <table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
                    <tr> 
                        <td colspan="2">text:
                        </td>
                        <td ><%# Eval("Text") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" />
                        </td>
                        <td>X:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Lon") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Y:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Lat") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Adding a `colspan=2` attribute to your :text label/header field.

Comment: still I get the same result.no change no shifting

Comment: Sorry, I left in an extra `<td>` for the pushpin header that I put in when I was trying something else. Try again.

Comment: Also, BTW, I find it helps when trying to debug these things to add the style: `td, th {outline: 1px solid red;}` to the stylesheet so you can see what is going on.